# Return original data set after top_n

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Given a data set, we can use `top_n` to limit the number of rows(ie sort/rank) we get back within the `tidyverse`. I love the flexibility of most `tidyverse` operations in that they can in most cases be undone ie you can go back to where you started.

Using data and a possible solution(I wrote) from a question on here, how can I best undo a `top_n`?.

**Data**:

```
df<-structure(list(milk = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L), bread = c(4L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 10L), juice = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L), honey = c(1L, 2L, 
0L, 3L, 1L), eggs = c(4L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L), beef = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 
1L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Code**:

```
df %>% 
  gather(key,value) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(Sum=sum(value)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Sum)) %>% 
  top_n(3,Sum) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

The above gives me this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  key     Sum
  <chr> <int>
1 eggs     23
2 bread    22
3 juice    20
```

Now what I would (learn how) to do is go back to the original data set without deleting code ie programmatically recover from a `top_n`:

Naturally I thought of `spreading`(`res` is the above result):

```
 spread(res,key,Sum)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  bread  eggs juice
  <int> <int> <int>
1    22    23    20
```

However, how to proceed from that or an alternative solution that undoes `top_n` just can't come to mind(yet). How can I best achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that how to get from a sum per group to all original individual values per group?

Comment: @tmfmnk That sounds like it.

Comment: Isn't `top_n` a `filter`, which you can't undo?

Comment: @CalumYou Right, seems that's what it does.

Comment: You can maybe do `cols <- df %>% 
 gather(key, value) %>% 
 group_by(key) %>% 
 summarise(Sum = sum(value)) %>% 
 arrange(desc(Sum)) %>% 
 top_n(3, Sum) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 pull(key)` and then `df %>%
 select(one_of(cols))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk Possibly, it however necessitates that I reuse the old data set. I thought(hoped) that there was a way something like how one can go from long to wide and back.

Comment: Theoretically, you can also do `df %>%
 select(one_of(df %>% 
                gather(key, value) %>% 
                group_by(key) %>% 
                summarise(Sum = sum(value)) %>% 
                arrange(desc(Sum)) %>% 
                top_n(3, Sum) %>%
                ungroup() %>%
                pull(key)))`.

Comment: Cool, that seems legit @tmfmnk thanks! It does the job albeit requiring first evaluating and getting the result.

Comment: Maybe even `df %>% 
 gather(key, value) %>% 
 group_by(key) %>%
 summarise(Sum = sum(value),
           Values = list(value),
           Row = list(row_number())) %>% 
 arrange(desc(Sum)) %>% 
 top_n(3, Sum) %>%
 select(-Sum) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 unnest() %>%
 spread(key, Values)`.

Comment: If you are using `top_n` you don't need to `arrange`.

Comment: @RonakShah I thought the same but `top_n()` doesn't sort; so `arrange` is needed if order is desired.

Comment: @Shree but this selects top 3 values `df %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%  
  gather(key, val) %>%
  top_n(3, val)` for the data without the need to `arrange`.

Comment: @RonakShah It selected top 3 but didn't sort result by `desc(Sum)`.

Comment: ahh..ok I see. I get what you mean but I thought in this case, it would be ok if the order is not maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar idea using `pull` but with slightly different approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%  # Your method of selecting 
  gather(key, val) %>%    # top three columns 
  top_n(3) %>%            # 
  arrange(-val) %>%       #
  pull(key) %>%           # pull 'key'
  select(df, .)           # select cols from df by `.`

#  eggs bread juice
#1    4     4     3
#2    4     5     4
#3    7     2     6
#4    3     1     5
#5    5    10     2
```

And, developing idea from the previous question:

```
df[, '['(names(sort(colSums(df), T)), 1:3)]
```

Which gives the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very dense base R solution:

```
df[, rank(-colSums(df))[1:3]]
  eggs bread juice
1    4     4     3
2    4     5     4
3    7     2     6
4    3     1     5
5    5    10     2
```

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily a reverse process, however, one possibility could be to select based on column names:

```
df %>% 
  gather(Key, Value) %>% 
  group_by(Key) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Value)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Sum)) %>%
  top_n(3, Sum) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pull(Key) %>% 
  {select(df, one_of(.))}

  eggs bread juice
1    4     4     3
2    4     5     4
3    7     2     6
4    3     1     5
5    5    10     2
```

Or a possibility where the values and row numbers are put into a list, then unnested and then spread:

```
df %>% 
 gather(Key, Value) %>% 
 group_by(Key) %>%
 summarise(Sum = sum(Value),
           Values = list(Value),
           Row_ID = list(row_number())) %>% 
 arrange(desc(Sum)) %>% 
 top_n(3, Sum) %>%
 select(-Sum) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 unnest() %>%
 spread(Key, Values) %>%
 select(-Row_ID)

  bread  eggs juice
  <int> <int> <int>
1     4     4     3
2     5     4     4
3     2     7     6
4     1     3     5
5    10     5     2
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept an answer after a few hours or a day. Just keeping it open in case someone else has an alternative.

Comment: @tmfmnk I think the answer with one_of() is the best so far. +1 I edited it a bit to improve readability. Feel free to rollback if you disagree with my changes.